# Modify Laptop Battery's internal status?

Tags: battery-life, battery, eeprom

Is there any way to modify the values of the laptop battery to make it fully charge?  I assume that these values are stored in EEPROM.

I would like to know if there is any tool that can read/write the battery's EEPROM directly from any OS.
On Linux I know there is a tool for UPS (apcsmart), but I don't know if it is possible to use it for laptop battery.

Comment: So really, you're talking about a laptop with a good battery, but the BIOS thinks it is bad.  So you want do so something to the BIOS to convince it that the battery is good?

Comment: It is not the BIOS that manage the battery but the EEPROM chip in the battery itself.

Answer (score -1):

Try this http://wiki.laptop.org/go/Battery_Charging#EEPROM_Init and let us know if it work.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: These instructions also seem very specific to the OLPC... it doesn't seem to specify if this will work for other computers/batteries.